# method chaining returning undefined

Tags: javascript, class, method-chaining

I have the following javascript class

```
var a = function () {
    this.data = {};
};

a.prototype.parseString = function (string) {
    this.data = string.split(',');
}

a.prototype.performOperationB = function () {
    this.iPo = _.map(this.data, function () {
        if (item.indexOf('ip') > -1) {
            return item;
        }
    });
}

a.prototype.save = function (string) {
    this.parseString(string)
        .performOperationB()
        // some other chained methods
}
var b = new a();

b.save(string);
```

would return `TypeError: Cannot read property 'performOperationB' of undefined`

Is it possible to chain the prototype methods one after another inside another method ?

Comment: I think you need filter here `this.iPo = _.map(this.data, function() {` instead of `map`

Comment: @tushar there was the problem that i had with my mapping function as well, but that was not the solution i was looking for. Thanks anyway mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return `this` from

```
a.prototype.parseString = function(string) {
   this.data  = string.split(',');
   return this;
}
```

because now method returns `undefined`

```js
var a = function () {
  this.data = {};
};

a.prototype.parseString = function (string) {
  this.data = string.split(',');
  return this;
}

a.prototype.performOperationB = function () {
  this.iPo = _.map(this.data, function (item) {
    if (item.indexOf('ip') > -1) {
      return item;
    }
  });
}

a.prototype.save = function (string) {
  this.parseString(string)
     .performOperationB()
}
var b = new a();

b.save('string');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```